What is wrong with this circuit
I can't figure this out. I am experimenting with a 555 and can't make blinking LEDs, they just stay on. Can anyone help me pinpoint what is wrong with the circuit?
(right resistor 500k, left resistor 1k, bottom resistors 220 ohms, 1 uF capacitor)
(The circuit simulation works perfectly)




You've left pin-4 (reset) floating. It needs to be pulled high.

and it's not clear in the pic of your physical circuit where the capacitor is connected - move the orange wire out the way and take another one.

Can you provide a schematic from which this breadboard implementation is made? It helps to see if (a) the design is correct or not and (b) if implementation matches the design or if it has errors.

The LED resistor appears to go to pin 2 rather than pin 3. If that is not it, move the end of the resistor that goes to pin 3 to +9V and verify that the LEDs light. You are using 3x yellow LEDs in series which should light dimly on 9V.

@brhans the circuit works in tinkercad though

@brhans the capacigor has positive connected to pin 2 and negative connected to pin1

@justme can the image above work as a schematic? the simulation works fine

@brhans how would I pull it high? Just connect to positive?

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany I actually changed it to pin 3 and thr leds still remain on

@Mr.Goose No, that's definitely not a schematic. If the drawn circuit matches the made circuit, there could still be a loose connection.

Yes, pull pin-4 to your positive supply (which you already have on pin-8).

@Mr.Goose Please post a schemtic

@VoltageSpike I posted it.  I think its  the same as the tinkercad pic

@wdym move the resistor to +9v? wouldn't that disconnect it  from pin 3? disconnecting it from the 555?

@Mr.Goose, One thing about your schematic is that for better practices, the battery should be connected to the power rail on the top of the breadboard.

@SnappyRiffs thank you, will make sure to do that next time. Do you know how I could fix the problem of thr LEDs?

Can you send me the tinkercad link

see this tutorial, for how to do it (first schematic is what you need).

why are you using three resistors in the LED circuit?

Your capacitor is not connected how your cartoon shows.  It is going to I think pin #1 on the 555, and I can't tell where the (-) end goes.  And as others point out, your E2 line connects to nothing.  Looks like you need to recheck your plugging-in work.  Also do you understand how the internal breadboard connections work?  Hopefully this isn't a final exam or something... if so, you might need to ask a classmate for some help!

@SnappyRiffs https://www.tinkercad.com/things/blZ3uibJvp9-neat-snaget-krunk?sharecode=2YT3KEAHJuFR2bEoRBSIf-JTB2SYmC5tXE3EfaokAPU

alright, the simulation looks like it works as you wanted

also how can the simulation work perfectly if it just stays on and you want it to blink

The timing resistor is 500 kohm in the simulator but 470 ohm in the physical circuit. So the flash frequency should be 1000 times faster, too fast for the human eye?
